# Java Swing JTable sort

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable with column headers.  When I click on a column header the data gets sorted.  This is the default sort behavior.

The thing is that I need to remember the last column the user clicked to sort.  Anyone knows which listener I need to implement in order to catch the column name that user clicked for sorting on the JTable?

The code is already implemented and I'm new to Swing. I just need to add that extra functionality. So any clues will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a MouseListener to the JtableHeader. Then you just use the columnAtPoint(...) method to determine when a column is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  So now how can I manually sort a column that will simulate a user clicking on a column? I couln't find a method that will do that.  Should I manually fire a MouseClicked event?

Comment: see the sort() method of the DefaultRowSorter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Swing-X](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) components, there is a JXTable which is more powerful than JTable.

Comment: Although this is a good suggestion, it doesn't answer the question.